# Electric Dipole force exerted by a charged wire on a dipole

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

*Why is force exerted by a charged wire on a dipole given as $F = P×(dE(r))/(dr)$ where P is the dipole moment?*

Please explain in simple words and avoid using too much technical derivations.I am a beginner so i'd appreciate if you could explain me how the formula originates in layman's terms.Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without equations:

The ideal dipole is made up of two oppositely charged particles infinitely close to each other. So we can immediately deduce that if the electric field does not change along the direction of the dipole, it exerts no force (because the force it exerts at the positive particle will identically cancel that at the negative one). The only way the electric field can exert force on the dipole is when the force it exerts on the positive particle is different from the force on the negative one, so the sum of the two forces is proportional to the difference in electric field between these two adjacent points (because of opposite charge and $F=qE$). Now as you know from calculus the limit of the difference of a function between two points as we take separation to zero is just the derivative. In the case of infinite wire, the electric field points radially outwards, so the force must too. The electric field also only changes radially, so the dipole will experience more force the more it points radially along the change of the electric field (e.g. if the dipole was parallel to the wire, there will be no change in the electric field "along" the dipole so it will experience zero force).

With equations (if you know multivariate calculus):

\begin{align*}
\vec{F} &= \vec{F}_+ + \vec{F}_- = q\vec{E}_+ - q\vec{E}_-  \\
& = \lim_{d\rightarrow 0} qd \frac{\vec{E}(\vec{x} + \vec{d}) - \vec{E}(\vec{x} - \vec{d})}{d} \\
&= \left( \vec{p}\cdot\vec{\nabla}\right)\vec{E}(\vec{x})
\end{align*}
$\left( \vec{p}\cdot\vec{\nabla}\right)$ just says in equations what we said in words : "variation along the dipole". The equation also shows that $\vec{F}$ is parallel to $\vec{E}$.